# Bring UIView over the current UIVIewController on a NavigationApplication

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, navigationcontroller

I develop a project which is based on `navigation` structure.

It is intended that in the current `ViewController` to display a generic view.This view contains information about the menu of the application.
I must show this uiview when user tap a button from the `navigation bar`.
I can't display this view over the current `viewcontroller`.

Can anyone help me?

I have a customNAvigation "

```
@interface CustomNavigation : UIView

- (IBAction)goToProfileInRootVC:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)goToRootinRootVC:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)goToPreviewVC:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)goToMenu:(id)sender;

+ (CustomNavigation*)showInView:(UIView*)parentView;

@end
```

When user tap on the Menu button from the navigtion I must display an UIView which must contain a list with the categories from menu.
 This view must be displayed over the current UIViewcontroller.

Comment: can u please explain more clearly??

Comment: dude, you need to show up some code.

Comment: How about adding the menu on Window? it will appear over everything ?

Comment: When you tap a button from navigation i must display a UIView with the menu elements.I must implement this dynamic...I tried to make  Uivie delegate and call it when user tap that button from navigation but without success...

Answer (score 1):

I just give you basic suggestion,

Add You view *(custom)* in `self.view` *(as Hidden)*, such like

```
self.mycustomView.hidden = YES; // default is hidden;
[self.view addSubView:self.mycustomView];
```

on Button click method, make this `mycustomView` is as visible

```
-(void)btnClick:(UIButton *)sender
{
  self.mycustomView.hidden = NO;
}
```

Comment: It's an application with a custom navigation.When you tap on the menu button from the navigation I must display a view which contain a list of categories.